# if statement within dplyr after group_by, do() and more chain/multiple conditions

Tags: r

I hope that you are all fine.

I have a dataset with many columns and I am trying to remove duplicated base on multiple criteria's.
Below I provide an example to demonstrate my problem. The idea is that for each ID all columns are checked and if all identical then keep the latest one. In case there are two identical rows and above comment is different then check if the row is "Add comment for down/upgrading client", if all rows have the same comment then keep the first row otherwise keep the latest  row without the above comment.

I have been trying the following

```
##dataframe
             ID <- c("H1", "H1"," H1"," H2", "H2", "H3", "H3"," H3", "H4")
            rating <-c("C", "C", "C+","D", "C", "C",  "C+", "C+", "C")
            Commnets<- c("Add comment for down/upgrading client", "updated", "Add comment for down/upgrading client","Add comment for down/upgrading client","Add comment for down/upgrading client", 
                        "down",  "down", "Add comment for down/upgrading client", "Add comment for down/upgrading client")
            Date<- c("2018-12-10", "2018-12-10", "2018-11-10",
                        "2018-11-10","2018-11-10", 
                        "2018-10-10",  "2018-10-02", "2018-10-02", "2020-09-03")
 df<-data.frame(ID,rating,Commnets,Date,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)






 df$Date<-as.Date(df$Date)
    df<-df%>%
      group_by(ID,rating,Date)%>%
      arrange(desc(Date)) %>% # in each group, arrange in desc by Date
      filter(row_number() == 1)#this will solve the first problem 



  
   



df$Date<-as.Date(df$Date)
        df<-df%>%
          group_by(ID,rating,Date)%>%
          arrange(desc(Date)) %>% #I think that I need **do** here but not sure how
ifelse(rowSums("Add comment for down/upgrading client" == $Comments)==length($Comments),
                  filter(row_number() == 1),rowSums("Add comment for down/upgrading client" == $Comments)[1,])
```

Comment: ifelse(rowSums("Add comment for down/upgrading client" == $Comments)==length($Comments),
                  filter(row_number() == 1),rowSums("Add comment for down/upgrading client" != $Comments)[1,])## else: I mean not equal it was a mistake on my post

Comment: You can edit your post to correct it. Can you show expected output for the data shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `arrange` the data by decreasing order of  `Date` and count number of unique  `Commnets` for each `ID`, `rating` and `Date`. If it's the same comment throughout select the 1st row and if it is different than select the last one i.e the latest one.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(ID = trimws(ID), 
         Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  arrange(ID, rating, Commnets, desc(Date)) %>%
  group_by(ID,rating,Date)  %>%
  slice(if(n_distinct(Commnets) == 1) 1L else n())

#  ID    rating Commnets                              Date      
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>                                 <date>    
#1 H1    C      updated                               2018-12-10
#2 H1    C+     Add comment for down/upgrading client 2018-11-10
#3 H2    C      Add comment for down/upgrading client 2018-11-10
#4 H2    D      Add comment for down/upgrading client 2018-11-10
#5 H3    C      down                                  2018-10-10
#6 H3    C+     down                                  2018-10-02
#7 H4    C      Add comment for down/upgrading client 2020-09-03
```

Comment: Hi Ronak Shah,
thank you very much for your prompt feedback.. Only one detail is missing from my side. On your posted example, as H3 has 3 entries, two of them are on the same date, but comment is different. For those that ID, rating and date is the same, but only comments change, please keep the one with comment different than "Add comment for down...". In our example it will be H3 has two of them with credit rating C+ on the same date, I would like to keep only the one with comment is "down"

Comment: @erv Check my updated answer if that is closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: @Roank Shah, thank you very much for this. It seems that it works, if I understood correct, in case the second comments start also from A then it will not work (am I correct?). As it works due to arrange and thus comments are sorted with A on top.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You need to define the conditions accurately according to the rows that you want to select.